# How does President Trump's follow-through on election promises compare to presidents in the past 20 years?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

That is to say - with nearly three years under his belt, how do President Trump's record of promises compare to other presidents past the year 2000?

In [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42185/what-has-donald-trump-accomplished-as-a-president-objectively), it is shown what promises President Trump has made during his campaign and how many of those were kept. One answer even provides a track record from Politifact on 102 promises made by Trump, and whether or not he delivered on them.

Compared to George W. Bush and Barack Obama at their point in their respective presidencies, has Trump kept and/or broken more or fewer promises?

Comment: It already has an answer at https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42185/what-has-donald-trump-accomplished-as-a-president-objectively (at least comparing to Obama).

Comment: This is going to be very subjective.

Comment: **Preventive notice:** This question is asking for objective, quantifiable, numbers. Please don't use this question as a pretext to discuss the merits of specific policies of Donald Trump or his predecessors. Also leave the interpretation of the numbers to the readers. Answers should be from a neutral point of view and refrain from criticizing or praising specific presidents.

Comment: My opinion on these kinds of questions (which seem to show up every month or so) is that they are fundamentally too subjective and opinion based to ever be answered properly on this site. Any answer would depend on what you consider to be a promise (vs a joke, opinion, or statement of values), what is needed to consider a promise "kept" and whether and how to consider things the president pushed for but that were blocked by congress. It's a good topic for a discussion forum, but I'd argue that it's impossible to write a neutral, objective answer to a question like this for any president.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad, largely because the history of Trump's Administration isn't finished yet. Despite the attempt to narrow the scope to just the first three years of his first term, it is too early for any equitable analysis. If historians are still evaluating George Washington's presidency, than it is literally too soon to Analyze Trumps to that depth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What has Donald Trump accomplished as a president (objectively)?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42185/what-has-donald-trump-accomplished-as-a-president-objectively)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy This question specifically references that question - I'm looking for a comparison to past presidents in this question.

Answer (score -1):

Not a full answer, but comments don't allow to post images. [Politifact](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/) offers a partial answer:

[Trump](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/):

[image: Trump-O-Meter]

[Obama](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/obameter/):

[image: Obameter]

Comment: Politifact is a bit generous to Trump, marking as 'stalled" his promises to "build a wall and have Mexico pay for it" and "Repeal Obamacare", whereas he has clearly given up on the first since he has appropriated US funds for his wall, and has about zero chance of repealing Obamacare with a Democratic house.

Comment: @DJClayworth: To me, their assessment of Trump is charitable bordering on plain wrong. This was intended as a comment with images more than anything. The point if any, btw, is that no, Trump is by no means keeping promises. Stalled = dead on arrival by now. In the works = working its way through courts now or at some point in the future, or being blocked by the House, which is also code word for dead on arrival. And Trump notoriously doesn't like to compromise, so methinks by the end of his presidency his "Promise Kept" slice will be slim indeed.

Comment: @DJClayworth Mexico is currently paying the salaries of people trying to stop migrants from reaching the USA. How is that not "Mexico is paying?" Maybe not for the wall, but at least for the goal of stopping migrants from entering the USA. If it turns out to be effective, this is close enough to get a "Promise Kept" in my book.  [And with that, it's clear that divibisan's comment is correct: "Any answer would depend on [..] what is needed to consider a promise 'kept'"]

Comment: When people suggested to Trump that border control be done by hiring people and not by a wall. Trump rejected that completely. And plenty of Democrat candidates agreed with enhanced expenditure on border security, but not a wall. So now you are saying that having achieved something that Trump himself rejected, but was agreed with by his opponents, is a "promise kept"? You deserve everything you get.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I guess the reasoning is that it's still possible seeing that Trump is still president (whereas Obama isn't and won't be in the future). For example, saying you will not raise the price on X and then doing it is a promise broken. Saying you will make Y free and not having done it yet is stalled (as it might happen tomorrow).